# Microsoft Ajax intellisense for visual studio 2012

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a hard time enabling intellisense, when using some Microsoft ajax global functions like $get. Is there a way to make it work in visual studio 2012. I tried using the reference below

```
///<reference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should be `path="yourFileName"`

If you drag the file over to your open .js tab, it'll add the reference for you. I have this in one of my .js files and it works fine:

```
/// <reference path="backbone-1.0.0.js" />
```